# Can I just cut the controller of Christmas lights

Tags: led

I can wire a plug safely, but electronics go over my head.
My daughter has some outside lights. 750 LEDs  750 x 0.064w / 3.2 - 6w.
The transformer is 31v / 6va.
The multi-function controller box states input 4.5v-36vdc  max 0.42A   output 4.5v - 36vdc`

If the output is the same as the input and the controller got wet and is not working. Can I just cut the controller off and rewire the transformer?

Obviously, safety is most important, and the lights will in future be powered from an external waterproof box.
The lights are dead so with caution, there is nothing to lose but I thought I would seek advice first.

Comment: What do you think chopping off the controller will achieve? Would any light turn on if they don't get any commands from controller?

Comment: wash and dry the controller

Comment: Gut the controller and try doing some reverse engineering. Post photos and results of your analysis and we can make a guess as to how they’re driven and their response to your proposed solution.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit lost here. I cannot find away to answer questions. If I can just get the lights to work without any functions thats OK.

Comment: The controller thoroughly dried out.

Comment: Hi. I just want to lights to come on static.

Comment: I am having a bit of trouble navigating the site. So, there is not much hope for me to do any repairs  I will try and open the box and see what is in there.

Comment: OK. Sorry but I find navigating this site difficult. How do I post a photograph please?